# Fastest execution time for querying on Big size table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

i need advice how to get fastest result for querying on big size table.
I am using SQL Server 2012, my condition is like this:

I have 5 tables contains transaction record, each table has 35 millions of records.
All tables has 14 columns, the columns i need to search is GroupName, CustomerName, and NoRegistration. And I have a view that contains 5 of all these tables.
The GroupName, CustomerName, and NoRegistration records is not unique each tables.

My application have a function to search to these column.
The query is like this:

Search by Group Name:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(GroupName) FROM TransactionRecords_view WHERE GroupName LIKE ''+@GroupName+'%'
```

Search by Name:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CustomerName) AS 'CustomerName' FROM TransactionRecords_view WHERE CustomerName LIKE ''+@Name+'%'
```

Search by NoRegistration:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(NoRegistration) FROM TransactionRecords_view WHERE LOWER(NoRegistration) LIKE LOWER(@NoRegistration)+'%'
```

My question is how can i achieve fastest execution time for searching?
With my condition right now, every time i search, it took 3 to 5 minutes.

My idea is to make a new tables contains the distinct of GroupName, CustomerName, and NoRegistration from all 5 tables.

Is my idea is make execution time is faster? or any other idea?

Thank you

---

EDIT:

This is query for view "TransactionRecords_view"

```
CREATE VIEW TransactionRecords_view
AS  
SELECT * FROM TransactionRecords_1507
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TransactionRecords_1506
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TransactionRecords_1505
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TransactionRecords_1504
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TransactionRecords_1503
```

Comment: So the columns are typed-in strings? You can enter a new transaction with GroupName 'NewGroup' and if you happen to have used that some years ago once, the new transaction is coincidentally in the same group? But if there is a typo like 'NewGrooup' then it's coincidentally a group on its own? I would rather expect a GroupName table with the transactions referring to its records.

Comment: `SELECT * ... UNION ALL`? So your five tables are all structured equally? Why then do you have five tables and not one? Wouldn't that be much better?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner because it's a transaction records each month. another function in my apps is calculate transaction per month, last month, and last year, so i thought split it up to each month would give better performance

Comment: I think this is a bad idea. SQL Server won't have a problem with handling some million or even billion records in one table. You are making things more complicated (and thus slower) than need be. Did you have any issues that your multiple table design solved?

Comment: Don't use a bunch of UNION ALL's, instead us a partitioned table (if you have the correct edition). Don't assume anything without looking at the query plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you don't need to make those new tables. If you create Non-Clustered indexes based upon these fields it will (in effect) do what you're after. The index will only store data on the columns that you indicate, not the whole table. Be aware, however, that indexes are excellent to aid in SELECT statements but will negatively affect any write statements (INSERT, UPDATE etc).

Next you want to run the queries with the actual execution plan switched on. This will show you how the optimizer has decided to run each query (in the back end). Are there any particular issues here, are any of the steps taking up a lot of the overall operator cost? There are plenty of great instructional videos about execution plans on youtube, check them out if you haven't looked at exe plans before.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I run the query using Actual Execution Time, and missing 2 indexes.

Answer (score 3):

You must show sql of TransactionRecords_view. Do you have indexes? What is the collation of NoRegistration column? Paste the Actual Execution Plan for each query.

Comment: IS that a **Answer** or **Comment**.

Comment: I already indexes each tables, but it only for another and more important function in my app. Forget to indexing for this function. Using Actual Execution Plan and missing 2 indexes. Thank you

Comment: @NeerajPrasadSharma this is a Comment with an Answer to consider by self :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to check if there were missing indexes with the actual execution plan ?

Moreover, as you use clause on varchar, I've heard about Full-Text Search.. maybe it can be useful for you  :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Full-Text Search seems good, but to use that i need to create Full-Text Index, and Full-Text Index need primary unique key, and the tables doesn't have a unique key. Thank you